If-statement and variable errors in javascript
I'm a JavaScript beginner and was taking an online course from YouTube. (03:19:00)
I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game using Math.random(). However, VS Code alerts the following messages:
 1. Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'randomNumber'.
 2. Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'computerMove'.
 3. Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'result'.

Can anyone explain why this happens and what the solution is?
The code is below.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Rock Paper Scissors</p>

    <button
      onclick="
   const randomNumber = Math.random();

   let computerMove = '';

   if (randomNumber >= 0 && randomNumber < 1 / 3 ) 
   {  
      computerMove = 'rock';

   }

   else if (randomNumber >= 1 / 3 && randomNumber < 2 / 3 )
   {
      computerMove = 'paper';

   }

   else if (randomNumber >= 2 / 3 && randomNumber < 1 )
   {
      computerMove = 'scissors';
   }



   let result = '';

   if (computerMove === 'rock'){
      
   result = 'Tie.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'paper' ) {
   result = 'Lost.';
   } else if (computerMove === 'scissors' ) {
   result = 'You win.';
   }
   alert (` You picked rock. Computer picked ${computerMove}.  ${result}.`)
  
  
  "
    >
      Rock
    </button>

    <button
      onclick=" 
   
   const randomNumber2 = Math.random();

   let computerMove = '';

   if (randomNumber2 >= 0 && randomNumber2 < 1 / 3 ) 
   {  
      computerMove2 = 'rock';

   }

   else if (randomNumber2 >= 1 / 3 && randomNumber2 < 2 / 3 )
   {
      computerMove2 = 'paper';

   }

   else if (randomNumber2 >= 2 / 3 && randomNumber2 < 1 )
   {
      computerMove2 = 'scissors';
   }

   let result2 = '';

   if (computerMove2 === 'rock'){
   resul2 = 'You win.';
   } else if (computerMove2 === 'paper' ) {
   result2 = 'Tie.';
   } else if (computerMove2 === 'scissors' ) {
   result2 = 'You lose.';
   }
   alert (` You picked paper. Computer picked ${computerMove2}.  ${result2}.`)
      "
    >
      Paper
    </button>

    <button
      onclick=" 
const randomNumber = Math.random();
   let computerMove = '';

if (randomNumber >= 0 && randomNumber < 1 / 3 ) 
{  
    computerMove = 'rock';

}

else if (randomNumber >= 1 / 3 && randomNumber < 2 / 3 )
{
    computerMove = 'paper';

}

else if (randomNumber >= 2 / 3 && randomNumber < 1 )
{
    computerMove = 'scissors';
}


let result = '';

if (computerMove === 'rock'){
   
result = 'You lose.';
} else if (computerMove === 'paper' ) {
result = 'You win.';
} else if (computerMove === 'scissors' ) {
result = 'Tie.';
}
alert (` You picked scissors. Computer picked ${computerMove}.  ${result}.`);

   
   "
    >
      Scissors
    </button>

    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>


Each time you click on a button the code is executed in the same scope and it is trying to declare already declared variables. try to move your code into a script function and call this function on click

@Thomas, please provide a source for the claim that this "code is executed in the same scope... trying to declare already declared variables".

@trincot, my bad, I trusted VS Code blindly ,  I am indeed wrong and declaring the same variable in several buttons as in the question is fine,
Thanks for your explanation in your answer.

This is a false positive coming from VS Code: it is not really an error and your code will run without that error. VS Code does not take into account that code that is assigned to a HTML attribute such as onclick, will run in its own block, as if the code were wrapped in its own function. So a variable that is declared in one such script is local to it and will not be available in another such inline script. VS Code misses that nuance and treats it (wrongly) as an error.
But taking a step back, it is really, really bad practice to put long blocks of code to onclick attributes (or any other HTML attributes). In fact, it is best practice to avoid that completely and attach event handlers via code, not via HTML.
Other remarks on your code:

randomNumber >= 0 is always true. Math.random() guarantees to return a number between 0 and 1 (1 excluded).

Instead of making checks like randomNumber < 1 / 3, it is easier to multiply the random number by 3, floor it to an integer, and then use that integer (which is 0, 1, or 2) as an index to pick one of the three options.

You repeat almost the same code three times. This can be avoided by using the same code for reacting to the three possible button clicks.

Instead of comparing strings, it will be easier to apply the logic to integers (which are 0, 1, or 2).

The logic of this game really is determined by modular arithmetic. It is completely determined by the expression playerMove - computerMove (mod 3).


There are many ways to implement this, but for your question the most important change is to use a function and place it in script, and have it called when the user clicks a button.
Example of how you could do it:


const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const outcomes = ["Tie", "You won", "You lost"];

function play(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "BUTTON") return; // Click was not on a button
    // Get both the player move and computer move as an integer in {0, 1, 2}.
    const playerMove = +e.target.id; // This is the number of the button that was clicked
    const computerMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    // The win-logic really is a matter of modular arithmetic:
    const result = (3 + playerMove - computerMove) % 3;
    alert (`You picked ${choices[playerMove]}. Computer picked ${choices[computerMove]}.  ${outcomes[result]}.`)
}

document.addEventListener("click", play); // Bind here, not in HTML
<button id="0">Rock</button>
<button id="1">Paper</button>
<button id="2">Scissors</button>




you are, actually, absolutely right, it's a function scope, I've messed it up in my answer
